# Keep the same code format no matter the IDE

Tags: unity, ide, monodevelop, visual-studio-code

In webdevelopment, there is a file called `.editorconfig` which have all the standards and format for the IDEs to follow, so no matter with what IDE you are working, the format will be the same.

This is an example of a .editorconfig file:

```
# editorconfig.org
root = true

[*]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
end_of_line = lf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true

[*.md]
trim_trailing_whitespace = false
```

Is there any way to have something similar in Unity, so, no matter what IDE our team use (MonoDevelop, VSCode, VStudio, Atom) we mantain the same style when formatting the documents?

It's really annoying to have a lot of commited changes when someone else simply reformatted the code with a different style.

Comment: MonoDevelop is the only one of those that doesn't have an .editorconfig plugin or built-in support. Can either convince your MD users to switch or conform the .editorconfig to whatever MD does?

Comment: MonoDevelop is generally disliked by most Unity developers, so really, showing your MD devs just how much more awesome Visual Studio is will make everyone happy.